# SQL - Mixing Exists with 'and' and 'or'

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm having trouble getting a viable query where I can have multiple required records and a single "one of two" exists.

I'm using Hibernate, hql, the sql obviously wouldn't be radically different, but it means that I can't use a full join (and therefore awkward).

What I basically want, but can't because I don't know how to mix inner and out exist calls :

```
select 1
from  application
where
application = ? and
exists (select 1 from x where ...) and
exists (select 1 from y where ...) and
exists ((exists (select 1 from Document where ...))
or 
(exists (select 1 from QA answer where ...)))
```

So I need x & y, but either Document or QA can be acceptable, as long as 1 exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select 1
from  application
where
application = ? and
exists (select 1 from x where ...) and
exists (select 1 from y where ...) and
(
    exists (select 1 from Document where ...)
    or 
    exists (select 1 from QA answer where ...)
);
```

Comment: That seems to work, at least in SQL.

Thank you! 
I thought I had tried that, but the overly complicated query must have meant an incorrect parenthesis. (I had suggest splitting the queries, but was shot down)